# Check for duplicates when using tab-separated txt file to generate iTunes playlist

Tags: csv, applescript, itunes

I'm using the following code in Applescript to generate iTunes playlists from a tab-separated .txt file. However, I wondered if there is a way of getting it to check if the files are already in the target playlist before adding each file?

```
set thisTSVFile to (choose file with prompt "Select the CSV file")
readTabSeparatedValuesFile(thisTSVFile)

set theList to readTabSeparatedValuesFile(thisTSVFile)

tell application "iTunes"
    set myPlaylist to playlist "InSLtxtLists"
    set sourcePlaylist to playlist "Music"
end tell

repeat with i from 2 to number of items in readTabSeparatedValuesFile(thisTSVFile)
    --gets first column
    set theName to item 1 of item i of theList
    --gets second
    set theArtist to item 2 of item i of theList
    tell application "iTunes"
        try
            duplicate (some track of sourcePlaylist whose name is theName and artist is theArtist) to myPlaylist
            on error the errorMessage
            set
        end try
    end tell
    delay 0.1
end repeat

on readTabSeparatedValuesFile(thisTSVFile)
    try
        set dataBlob to (every paragraph of (read thisTSVFile))
        set the tableData to {}
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
        repeat with i from 1 to the count of dataBlob
            set the end of the tableData to (every text item of (item i of dataBlob))
        end repeat
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        return tableData
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        error errorMessage number errorNumber
    end try
end readTabSeparatedValuesFile
```

For reference, each line in the .txt file is formatted like this:
`'Allo 'Allo! Theme (David Croft & Roy Moore)   Jack Emblow 1982`

Comment: "iTunes" -- What version of **macOS** are you running? Anyway, you need to compare the _value_ of `theName` against the a `list` of the `name of tracks`, e.g. `if (name of tracks of playlist myPlaylist" does not contain theName then ...`

Comment: OS Mojave 10.14.6 if that helps!

Comment: So wrap an 'if' block around the tell blocks @user3439894 ? Or is there a specific place I should put it?

Comment: `if (name of tracks of playlist myPlaylist) does not contain theName then duplicate (some track of sourcePlaylist whose name is theName and artist is theArtist) to myPlaylist`